# How to decode an http response data from URLSession and map to a response structure swift

Tags: swift, urlsession, jsondecoder

I am new to swift programming..was able to obtain a successful response from URLSession but I am unable to parse (decode) the data object to my desired APIResponse Structure

this is my url request code:

```
func load(urlRequest: URLRequest, withCompletion completion: @escaping (_ response: APIResponse) -> Void) {
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error fetching data from server\nERROR: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            
            guard let jsonData = data else {
                print("Response Data is empty")
                return
            }
            
            printResponseBody(response: data)
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response = try? decoder.decode(APIResponse.self, from: jsonData)
            
            guard let decodedResponse = response else {
                print("Unable to parse data from response")
                return
            }
            
            print("Decoded Response: ", decodedResponse)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(decodedResponse) }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

and here is my response structure which i need the response data to map to to use in my code:

```
struct APIResponse: Codable {
    
    let responseCode: Int
    let data: ResultSet
    let meta: Meta

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case responseCode = "response_code"
        case data, meta
    }
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct ResultSet: Codable {
    
    let appVersionUpdate: String
    let offers: [Offer]
    let rate: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case appVersionUpdate = "app_version_update"
        case offers, rate
    }
}

// MARK: - Offer
struct Offer: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let image: String?
    let r, resultCount: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, r = "r"
        case title, image
        case resultCount = "result_count"
    }
}

// MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Codable {
    
    let apiVersion: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case apiVersion = "api_version"
    }
```

this is the json from server which I am trying to decode

```
 {
    "response_code": 0,
    "data": {
        "app_version_update": "",
        "offers": [
            {
                "title": "Special Scheme1",
                "image": "http://59.145.109.138:11101/Offers/BGL_banner_1080_x_540_1.jpg",
                "r": 1.0,
                "result_count": 5.0
            },
            {
                "title": "test 1",
                "image": "http://59.145.109.138:11101/Offers/Yoho-National-Park2018-10-27_10-10-52-11.jpg",
                "r": 2.0,
                "result_count": 5.0
            },
            {
                "title": "Offer Test 1234444",
                "image": "http://59.145.109.138:11101/Offers/Stanley-Park2018-10-27_10-11-27-44.jpg",
                "r": 3.0,
                "result_count": 5.0
            }
        ],
        "rate": 2000
    },
    "meta": {
        "api_version": 2.0
    }
 }
```

whenever i run this code i am getting the "unable to parse data from response" error. Would really appreciate if someone tells me what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with decoding the `id` in `Offer`. Replace your `Offer` with this:

```
struct Offer: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let image: String?
    let r, resultCount: Int

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id, r, title, image, resultCount
        
        var stringValue: String {
            switch self {
            case .id, .r: return "r"
            case .title: return "title"
            case .image: return "image"
            case .resultCount: return "result_count"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- First of all, you shouldn't have gotten rid of the error. Instead you could print the error and try to find out whats going wrong.
- If you declare `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey`, the raw value for each case **Must** be different from the other or the Xcode will complain. In your case it didn't complain because `id` is the requirement of the `Identifiable` protocol, but it also didn't even use the raw value that you set for `id`. If you want to use the same key for 2 different variables, you should do the same thing i did above.

#### Better code

This will work the same as the your code, but is quite cleaner:

```
struct Offer: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: Int { r }
    let title: String
    let image: String?
    let r, resultCount: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case r, title, image, resultCount
    }
}
```

It basically says everytime you need `id`, get it from `r`. You can also remove the `stringValue` in `CodingKeys` as i did, and use the `CodingKeys: String` conformation.

Comment: thank you so much..I got the correct response..really appreciate it.. will surely consider your advice..can you also please send me a generic version of the same code which i can use for multiple apis where only the data section of the json response changes rest all remains the same...